# Recycler view Header misplaced from Position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have included a Recycler view with a header contains 2 buttons. It is working fine but when I tried to navigate inside the app and comeback on the same screen it seems that header button moves down by its actual position and overlap Recyclerview item.

Fragment:

```
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mDashboardActivity);
    mHomeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    mHomeRecyclerViewAdapter = new HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(mDashboardActivity);
    mHomeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHomeRecyclerViewAdapter);

    mHomeRecyclerViewHeader = RecyclerViewHeader.fromXml(mDashboardActivity, R.layout.header_home_recycle);
    mHomeRecyclerViewHeader.attachTo(mHomeRecyclerView, false);
```

Adapter:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_home, parent, false);
    return new SampleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SampleViewHolder viewHolder = (SampleViewHolder) holder;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 10;
}

public static class SampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvReqRec;

    public SampleViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        tvReqRec = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvReqReceived);
        tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    }
}
```

Anyone please do help me to fix the issue.

Comment: share your code please so we can help you